# What size beams do I need for my shed roof?

Tags: roof, beam, dormer

Looking for advice on sizing roof beams for a 24’ wide x 24’ deep 4/12 pitch ‘shed dormer’ to cover a deck, no gables - just flat pitched roof structure, using timber or engineered lumber, and using polycarbonate panels for allowing light through.

And I should mention my wife does not want it to be ‘chunky’ , so timber frame is out.

We Live in upstate NY, snow load 60lb./ft.<sup>2</sup>, dead load just weight of panels 10lb./ft.<sup>2</sup>! And not sure of wind - but it is a big structure so maybe design for 70 mph winds??

Using BC calc and 100#/ft^2 can use their 3100 SP product and triple or quad with like 17-1/4” beam height .

But although the roof will be dry, it is to be unsheathed and also we want to paint the beams white.

We currently use a 20’ x 20’ frame tent (only four legs of west coast design , high in center with four tapering sides - one does taper toward building, but we use a rain gutter system so no water floods, this is not a high peaked Rennaisance tent)  and the tent is taken  down for winter - but 24’ x 24’ would provide more space and extend season of use.

The upper part is proposed to be attached at a ledger beam at frost board which is 16’ high (wall is 16’4” high x 24’6” wide with windows, transom windows  and double French door. Which leads to deck.

Appreciate very much advice/suggestions.

We are in early design/concept / brainstorming phase.

By the way the polycarbonate panels are available 24”, 36”, 48”, 72” and 83” wide.  25mm thick and up to 24’ long. At additional transportation charges.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need trusses or TJIs for that span, and talk to an engineer (or the "truss guy" at the lumberyard, who will have a program that will spit out results that will pass an engineering check.)

Answer (score 0):

The beam will be supported by 4 posts, of which I assume will be equally spaced. This creates 3 equal clear spaces of 8’.

The total load is 60 psf Live Load plus 10 psf Dead Load = 70 psf.

Therefore, the total load on the beam is 70 psf x 24’ / 2 = 840 plf.

I’m not sure where the 17 1/4” high dimension came from, but a SPF 4x10 will support about 800 plf of Select Structural grade and a 4x12 will support about 1,000 plf of Select Structure Grade and 750 plf of standard No. 2 and better grade.

Therefore, a 4x12 seems to be the most appropriate and common size. There are standard steel post caps to fit such a beam and standard 4x4 posts could be used, depending on the height of the beam.

Answer (score 0):

The Boise Cascade calculation on line returned beam thickness of 17-1/4” for the span and dead, live, and wind loads.

Thanks to those who responded.

Comment: If this is intended to be your answer (i.e. what you're going to use), please click the check-mark so others will know that it's got an answer. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that's how things work here.

Comment: Other than strength, make sure the suggested beam size will yield a tolerable deflection.